# Unable to Widget Test a Container that is rendered after a delay of 3 seconds in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

**Scenario**

I have a simple scenario where there are two buttons, one to render a blue colored Container immediately and the other to render a red colored Container after a delay of 3 seconds.

**Code**

*loginpage_test.dart*

```
void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  testWidgets('test for blue and red boxes', (tester) async {
    // Arrange
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MainApp());
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MaterialApp(
      home: DashboardPage(),
    ));

    // Act
    Finder blueButtonFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey('BlueButton'));
    Finder blueBoxFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey('BlueBox'));
    Finder redButtonFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey('RedButton'));
    Finder redBoxFinder = find.byKey(const ValueKey('RedBox'));

    // Assert
    expect(blueButtonFinder, findsOneWidget);
    expect(blueBoxFinder, findsNothing);
    expect(redButtonFinder, findsOneWidget);
    expect(redBoxFinder, findsNothing);

    await tester.tap(blueButtonFinder);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(blueBoxFinder, findsOneWidget);

    await tester.runAsync(() async {
      await tester.tap(redButtonFinder);
      // await tester.binding.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
      await tester.pumpAndSettle();
      // await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 3));
    });

    expect(redBoxFinder, findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

*dashboardpage.dart*

```
class DashboardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DashboardPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DashboardPage> createState() => _DashboardPageState();
}

class _DashboardPageState extends State<DashboardPage> {
  bool isShowBlue = false;
  bool isShowRed = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.black20,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.menu_rounded, size: 24.w),
        actions: AppbarActions.appBarActions,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        systemOverlayStyle: CustomOverlays.appbarOverlayLight,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.w),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CoverPictureSection(),
            SizedBox(height: 10.h),
            ElevatedButton(
              key: const ValueKey('BlueButton'),
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  isShowBlue = true;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Create Blue Box'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.h),
            isShowBlue
                ? Container(
                    key: const ValueKey('BlueBox'),
                    width: 50.w,
                    height: 50.h,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  )
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
            SizedBox(height: 10.h),
            ElevatedButton(
              key: const ValueKey('RedButton'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
                setState(() {
                  isShowRed = true;
                });
              },
              child: const Text('Create Red Box'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 10.h),
            isShowRed
                ? Container(
                    key: const ValueKey('RedBox'),
                    width: 50.w,
                    height: 50.h,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  )
                : const SizedBox.shrink(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Problem**

The test for the blue box completes successfully, but for the red box the test fails with the following error:

**══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching candidate
Actual: _KeyWidgetFinder:<Found 0 widgets with key [<'RedBox'>]: []>
Which: means none were found but one was expected**

It seems that the future is not completed before the expect for red box is called. I looked for solutions online which suggested that I run the `tester.tap` for `RedBox` inside `runAsync()` but still get the same error.

**Request**

I would like to know how I can successfully widget test a widget that is rendered after a Future induced delay. What changes do I need to make to my code?

Comment: After I add `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));` inside `runAsync()`, I don't get this error. However I get a new error: **Error: google_fonts was unable to load font Poppins-Regular because the following exception occurred:
Exception: Failed to load font with url:**

Don't google font enabled widgets work inside runAsync()?

Answer (score 0):

I added `await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));` `inside the runAsync()`

I got a new error: **Error: google_fonts was unable to load font Poppins-Regular because the following exception occurred: Exception: Failed to load font with url**

Then I referred to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75720850/19413610 and downloaded the .ttf, added it to assets folder and re-ran the test. It ended successfully.